# How to solve $\log(1+ax)=b\log(1+x)?$

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms

I want to solve this equation for $x$:

$\log(1+ax)=b\log(1+x)$

In this equation $a,b>1$. Would you please help how should I do that or what should I study?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the fact that $b \log(1+ x) = \log(1 + x)^b$. Now, try to exponentiate both sides.

Comment: @devianceee I did, but have no idea for that, neither!

Comment: You have to show your work. MSE isn't a homework service site. I don't know why you 're hoping for a numerical solution when you only have variables.

Comment: @Cheesecake This problem is obtained when I wanted to calculate the Angle of Arrival in a wireless system (It's not my homework). Please let me know how much more information I should add to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, we know that:

$$\ln\left(x^y\right)=y\ln\left(x\right)\tag1$$

So:

$$\ln\left(1+ax\right)=b\ln\left(1+x\right)=\ln\left(\left(1+x\right)^b\right)\tag2$$

Now, taking $\exp$ on both sides leads to:

$$1+ax=\left(1+x\right)^b\tag3$$

> Now, you can see the problem why it is not easy to solve for a general $x$.

Comment: So, it is not possible to have an exact solution? What about numerical one?

Comment: There is one trivial exact solution: $x=0$.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak Of course

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$n\cdot \log x = \log x^n$